# How to change Postgres primary key column values?

Tags: postgresql, query, primary-key

My postgres database has a column called "id" that runs from 40,000,000 to about 50,000,000. The "id" column is the primary key. I need to change the "id" column values such that they span different numbers in order to merge this database with another.

How can I go about generating code to change the values from 40,000,000 - 50,000,000 to, say, 0 - 10,000,000?

The table definition is

```
CREATE TABLE public.keyvaluehistory (
   id bigint NOT NULL
      DEFAULT nextval('keyvaluehistory_id_seq'::regclass),
   segkey text NOT NULL,
   dvalue double precision,
   bvalue bytea,
   tstamp timestamp with time zone,
   CONSTRAINT keyvaluehistory_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

There are no foreign keys on the table.

I can afford downtime on the order of minutes/hours.

Comment: Subtract 40,000,000?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would add another column temporarily.

The first part can run while the database is active:

```
ALTER TABLE keyvaluehistory ADD new_id bigint;

CREATE SEQUENCE keyvaluehistory_new_id_seq OWNED BY keyvaluehistory.new_id;

/* update in batches to avoid table bloat */

UPDATE keyvaluehistory SET new_id = id - 39999999
   WHERE id BETWEEN 40000000 AND 40999999;

VACUUM keyvaluehistory;

UPDATE keyvaluehistory SET new_id = id - 39999999
   WHERE id BETWEEN 41000000 AND 41999999;

VACUUM keyvaluehistory;

...

SET maintenance_work_mem = '1GB';

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CONCURRENTLY keyvaluehistory_new_pkey (new_id);
```

The following part locks the table and requires down time.

The most time consuming part is adding the primary key, because that requires scanning the table.

```
/* downtime starts here */

BEGIN;

LOCK TABLE keyvaluehistory IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE;

/* catch up */

UPDATE keyvaluehistory SET new_id = id - 39999999
   WHERE new_id IS NULL;

ALTER TABLE keyvaluehistory
   DROP CONSTRAINT keyvaluehistory_pkey;

ALTER TABLE keyvaluehistory
   DROP COLUMN id;

ALTER TABLE keyvaluehistory
   ADD CONSTRAINT keyvaluehistory_pkey USING keyvaluehistory_new_pkey;

ALTER INDEX keyvaluehistory_new_pkey RENAME TO keyvaluehistory_pkey;

ALTER TABLE keyvaluehistory RENAME new_id TO id;

ALTER SEQUENCE keyvaluehistory_new_id_seq RENAME TO keyvaluehistory_id_seq;

SELECT setval('keyvaluehistory_new_id_seq', 10000001);

COMMIT;
```

Please test befor running it in production; I may have forgotten something.

Comment: This worked! There was some language/variable mismatch with the indexes and constraints but I managed to work it out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Laurenz: can you explain why `VACUUM` after each block avoids table-bloat?

Comment: @TmTron Because it removes the dead row versions created in the preceding step, so that the space can be reused by the next `UPDATE`. See the PostgreSQL documentation.